# Reemplazar texto de etiquetas XML con Shell

Tags: xml, bash, shell, shell-script, sed

estoy intentando reemplazar un cadena de texto de un archivo XML por otro usando el comando la herramienta **Sed**, pero no consigo obtener el resultado que espero.

Comando:

```bash
sed -i -e -r 's|test-plugin.+\s\s*?<version>(.+)<\/version>|test-plugin.+\s\s*?<version>1.0.0<\/version>|g' plugins.xml
```

XML:

```xml
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <name>test-plugin</name>
          <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <name>test-plugin-2</name>
          <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <name>test-plugin-3</name>
          <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

El resultado que espero es que substituya la **versión** del **primer** plugin ya que es el que coincide con el nombre dado en el propio comando. Obviamente que lo sustituya respetando los saltos de línea y espacios de la estructura XML.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahorita no se me ocurre una versión más corta con `awk`, pero definitivamente con `sed` sería un dolor innecesario.

Intenta con esto:

```
 $ awk '/<name>test-plugin<\/name>/{seen=1;print ; next}; seen {gsub(/3.0.0/, "1.0.0"); seen=0};1' archivo.xml
```

Lo que hago aquí es que cuando encuentro el nombre del plugin, le asigno un 1 a la variable "seen" (osea, lo pongo en True), luego imprimo la línea y le pido a `awk` que vea la siguiente línea, y luego, si la variable `seen` es True (tiene el valor 1), substituya el número de versión y luego ponga en false la variable `seen`.

Con el número 1, ahí solo, solo le pido que imprima por defecto el renglón, que para estas altura ya habrá sido modificado o será cualquier otro que no cumpla las condiciones de la regex.

### Update

Ya que me decidí hacerlo con `sed`, esta sería la respuesta:

```
$ sed '/<name>test-plugin<\/name>/{n;s/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/}' archivo.xml
```

Lo que hacemos es que el nombre del plugin va a hacer que se ejecute lo que esté entre las llaves {}.

Y lo que está entre las llaves es:

- "n", que añade la siguiente línea al *pattern space*
- "s/pattern/replacement/", que reemplazará el patrón por su reemplazo.

La verdad no fue tanto dolor como el que creí que sería.

Comment: Cuando vi el comando de awk tengo que reconocer que me explotó la cabeza, pero la update con Sed está bastante bien y funciona de las mil maravillas, muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: Pues hacen lo mismo de la misma manera pero con sus propias funciones y funcionalidades.

Answer (score 2):

Intenté ayudándole usando las `regex` pero puede ser bastante complejo y difícil de mantener ya que no sería tan flexibe a los cambios (algo que tiene que tener en cuenta), incluso con `awk` que es mucho más poderoso que `sed`, lo que si puede hacer es generar un script en python para que haga lo que necesita. Le dejo el código (personalmente prefiero la 2 versión de este ejemplo):

**1ra versión**

```
import re 
f = open("/ruta/a_su_archivo/archivo.xml", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
plugin_name = "test-plugin"
new_version_of_plugin = '2.5.3'

for i in range(len(lines)):
    if re.search(f"<name>{plugin_name}<\/name>", lines[i]):
        lines[i+1] = re.sub("<version>.*</version>",f"<version>{new_version_of_plugin}</version>", lines[i+1])
        print(lines[i+1])
print(lines)

f = open("/ruta/a_su_archivo/archivo.xml", "w+")
f.writelines(lines)
f.close()
```

lo puede guardar con cualquier nombre, para este ejemplo se guarda como `nombre_del_script.py` y lo invoca así:

```
python3 nombre_del_script.py
```

También puede recibir la ruta del archivo y la versión por consola, en ese caso cambiría el código a:

**2da versión**

```
import re 
import sys

file = sys.argv[0]
plugin_name = sys.argv[1]
new_version_of_plugin = sys.argv[2]

f = open(file, "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

for i in range(len(lines)):
    if re.search(f"<name>{plugin_name}<\/name>", lines[i]):
        lines[i+1] = re.sub("<version>.*</version>",f"<version>{new_version_of_plugin}</version>", lines[i+1])
        print(lines[i+1])
print(lines)

f = open(file, "w+")
f.writelines(lines)
f.close()
```

y lo invoca así (obviamente cambia por los valores correspondientes):

```
python3 nombre_del_script.py ruta_al_archivo.xml nombre_del plug_in version_que_quiere_colocar
```

Comment: Yo tiendo a estar de acuerdo con que uno [no debería manipular XML con regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/236345)

Comment: Te quiero poner un punto, pero el hecho que tengas que escribir un programa entero en Python para eso (y luego sin usar manejadores de contexto con la sentencia `with`) se me hace medio :/, porque no estamos explotando las utilidades de GNU/Linux.

Comment: Pero bueno, listo, buen código.

Comment: Te doy un punto por el hecho de haber hecho un programa en python para ello, pero no me sirve ya que lo necesito en bash. Gracias :)